# InstallAnywhere issue: This application has unexpectely quit

Tags: java, odbc, dsn, installanywhere

I have downloaded IBM Client SDK 4.10 FC5DE for Windows x64. When I proceed to install it, InstallAnyWhere popups saying "Preparing installation files...". When it reaches to 100% below error is shown and installation terminates:

```
This application has unexpectely quit:
Invocation of this Java application has caused an InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit (LAX).
```

And If I click on details button its show stack trace:

```
ZeroGu6: Windows DLL failed to load
    at ZeroGa4.b(DashoA10*..)
    at ZeroGa4.b(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.b(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(DashoA10*..)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)
```

My OS is Windows 8.1 Pro and I have the last Java x86 and Java x86_64 installed on my system. Java x86_64 is the only activated in Java configuration panel. If I activated both, it does not work either. Leaving activating Java x86 it does not work either.

Below the Java packages installed on my system:

- Java 8 Update 151
- Java 8 Update 151 (64-bit)
- Java(TM) SE Development Kit 6 Update 24

So any ideas on what is happening?

**SOLVED**:
I have solved it.

In order to work you need to set Compatibility Mode to Windows 7 for setup ( executable file).

Right click on setup file, go to compatibility tab, and then set "Compatibility Mode" to "Windows 7". Also in configuration, you can check "Launch this program as Administrator".

Link where I found a similar problem: see [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=1942b6c8-498a-4681-aefb-7d0e0ce0c937).

Comment: StackOverflow is a coding site. You should post this at SuperUser instead: https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change compatibility to windows 7

Check [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21686842) (not the same product, but looks like the same error)

> The installation can be finished successfully while setting the two
>   files below to Windows 7 compatibility mode.
>
> File 1: launchpad64.exe launchpad.exe, depending on which bit version you plan to install
>
> File2: depending on the used launchpad version, 64 or 32 bit, go into 
>       a. win86_64 (If you are running launchpad64.exe) or 
>       b. win86_32 (If you are running launchpad.exe) folder.
>
> If you Install as Administrator, change the compatibility of install.exe to
>   Windows 7.
>
> If you Install as Current User, change the compatibility of
>   userinst.exe to Windows 7.
>
> Launch the launchpad64.exe or launchpad.exe
>   as Administrator

Comment: Yes, correct. I solved it doing this. I found a similar error here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=1942b6c8-498a-4681-aefb-7d0e0ce0c937 Anyway thanks for you answer, I accept it.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't solve the problem for me. I have admin mode and Windows 7 compatibility enabled, but the error still occurrs.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this problem today. Set Compatibility Mode to Windows 7 doesnt work for me. But this way does:
Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment variables -> Add new user variable:

- Name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
- Value: "-Dos.name=Windows 7"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was experiencing the same issue today.

Canillas' answer works, but it is a workaround. Windows compatibility mode introduces a whole new layer of potential problems. It is, in fact, a layer that takes system calls and attempts to emulate how they would perform on a previous version of Windows, using the current version of Windows.

The problem is the JRE version. Use 1.8u45. If you do not want to add the bin folder to your PATH variable, then run the installer will the LAX_VM parameter pointing to java.exe.

I do not know what changed in the next JRE build, but something broke the version of InstallAnywhere you are using.